# Acumatica: How can order by in PXSelector

Tags: acumatica

I want to order by "HierachyLevel" but it's not working. PXSelector always order by SubstitudeKey. Below is my property in DAC

```
[PXInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Hierarchy Level")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search3<DMSAttributeConfig.attributeNbr, 
    OrderBy<Asc<DMSAttributeConfig.hierachyLevel>>>),
    typeof(DMSAttributeConfig.attribute),
    typeof(DMSAttributeConfig.userValue),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(DMSAttributeConfig.attribute),
    DescriptionField = typeof(DMSAttributeConfig.userValue))]
public int? AttributeNbr { get; set; }
```

---

Updated, DB Entries as below and I want PXSelector result like it.

```
AttributeNbr  |  Attribute     |  HierachyLevel
1             |  Category      |  1
2             |  Sub-Category  |  2 
3             |  Brand         |  3
4             |  Sub-Brand     |  4
```

And current PXSelector result is

```
AttributeNbr  |  Attribute     |  HierachyLevel
3             |  Brand         |  3
1             |  Category      |  1 
4             |  Sub-Brand     |  4
2             |  Sub-Category  |  2
```

Sorry for late

Comment: Can you please add example of your DB entries? I need it for providing help more quickly

Comment: I'm running into a situation such as this.  It appears that as soon as you add the SubstituteKey the resulting SQL is auto-sorted first by the key, then the rest of the orderby.